# Interchangeable, composite primary keys

Tags: sql, composite-primary-key

I have a table `foo` that has only two fields: `fooIdA` and `fooIdB` (both of the same type). Those are composite primary keys, so:

```
primary key (fooIdA, fooIdB)...
```

Considering this, how can I make all permutations of the keys to be the same?
That is, `(fooIdA, fooIdB) = (fooIdB, fooIdA)`.

Comment: Do you mean when you insert one primary key to insert also the other permutation of it?

Comment: @αNerd no, I want that the other permutation be considered duplicate of the first one.

Comment: You can use trigger to check if the other combination is already present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your DBMS, you can create a unique index on an expression that prevents inserting `(1,2)` and `(2,1)`

In Postgres and Oracle you can do this:

```
create unique index unique_combinations 
    on the_table (least(fooida, fooidb), greatest(fooida, fooidb));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify your RDBMS. You can also add calculated fields with MAX, MIN values and add UNIQUE constraint on these calculated fields. Here is the MSSQL example:

```
CREATE TABLE ATest (id1 int, id2 int);

ALTER TABLE ATest ADD idMax AS (CASE WHEN id1>=id2 THEN id1 ELSE id2 END);  
ALTER TABLE ATest ADD idMin AS (CASE WHEN id1>=id2 THEN id2 ELSE id1 END);  
ALTER TABLE ATest ADD CONSTRAINT UniqueConstCalc UNIQUE(idMax,idMin);

insert into ATest values (1,1);
insert into ATest values (1,2);
insert into ATest values (2,1);

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UniqueConstCalc'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ATest'. 
The duplicate key value is (2, 1).
The statement has been terminated.
```